# HTML5 FileReader how to return result?

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

I use JS FileReader. I want to get result after file reading operation and work with this data. FileReader is asynchronous and I don't know when result is ready. How to get it done right?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#file_input').on('change', function(e){
        var res = readFile(this.files[0]);

        //my some manipulate with res

        $('#output_field').text(res);
    });
});

function readFile(file){
    var reader = new FileReader(),
        result = 'empty';

    reader.onload = function(e)
    {
        result = e.target.result;
    };

    reader.readAsText(file);

    //waiting until result is empty?

    return result;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ub22m/4/

It's show "empty".

How to wait until "result" is empty? 
Another way?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Reading happens *asynchronously*. You need to provide a custom `onload` callback that defines what should happen when the read completes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#file_input').on('change', function(e){
        readFile(this.files[0], function(e) {
            // use result in callback...
            $('#output_field').text(e.target.result);
        });
    });
});

function readFile(file, onLoadCallback){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = onLoadCallback;
    reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

(See the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PkRpW/).)

Note that `readFile` does not return a value.  Instead, it accepts a callback function, which will fire whenever the read is done. The `$('#output_field').text` operation is moved into the callback function.  This ensures that that operation will not run until the reader's `onload` callback fires, when `e.target.result` will be filled.

Programming with callbacks is a bit difficult to get right at first, but it is absolutely necessary for implementing advanced functionality.

Comment: Is there a difference between the two `e`s?

Comment: @ChrisChudzicki Yes, they are different. The first `e` is [jQuery event object](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/). The second `e` is [load event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load).

Answer (score 9):

Use a Promise to wrap FileReader and then use `await` to get the results:

https://blog.shovonhasan.com/using-promises-with-filereader/

Answer (score 2):

Here's the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#file_input').on('change', function(e) {

        function updateProgress(evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                // evt.loaded and evt.total are ProgressEvent properties
                var loaded = (evt.loaded / evt.total);
                if (loaded < 1) {
                    // Increase the prog bar length
                    style.width = (loaded * 200) + "px";
                }
            }
        }

        function loaded(evt) {
            // Obtain the read file data    
            var fileString = evt.target.result;
            // Handle UTF-16 file dump
            $('#output_field').text(fileString);
        }
        var res = readFile(this.files[0]);

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.readAsText(this.files[0], "UTF-8");

        reader.onprogress = updateProgress;
        reader.onload = loaded;


    });
});

function readFile(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader(),
        result = 'empty';

    reader.onload = function(e) {
        result = e.target.result;
    };

    reader.readAsText(file);

    return result;
}
```

And of course, the HTML portion:

```
<input type="file" id="file_input" class="foo" />
<div id="progBar" style="background-color:black;width:1px;"> </div>
<div id="output_field" class="foo"></div>
```

Seems to work for *.txt files.

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adouga/8yswa/).

Comment: strange, fiddle reverted back to the old version. Fixed now.

Comment: return is a keyword that I believe was being mentioned here. The readFile function will always return 'empty'

Answer (score 1):

**use case FileReader**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function PreviewImage() {
            var oFReader = new FileReader();
            oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);
            oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
                var sizef = document.getElementById('uploadImage').files[0].size;
                document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
                document.getElementById("uploadImageValue").value = oFREvent.target.result; 
            };
        };
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $('#viewSource').click(function ()
            {
                var imgUrl = $('#uploadImageValue').val();
                alert(imgUrl);
            });
        });
        </script>
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" id="uploadImageValue" name="uploadImageValue" value="" />
            <img id="uploadPreview" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" /><br />
            <input id="uploadImage" style="width:120px" type="file" size="10" accept="image/jpeg,image/gif, image/png" name="myPhoto" onchange="PreviewImage();" />
        </div>
        <a href="#" id="viewSource">Source file</a>
    </body>
</html>
```