# Return value is 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, return-value, onchange

Why is the return value 'undefined'? Sorry I am a newbie :)

```
// Reading file
function Reading(event, i) {
    var file = event.target.files[i];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var txt;
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        // txt == defined
        txt = event.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
    // txt == undefined
    return txt;             
}
```

I want to do something with the text... not only show text in box.

Comment: More specific dupe: [_HTML5 FileReader how to return result?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829537/html5-filereader-how-to-return-result)

Comment: I want to do something with the text... not only show text in box.

Comment: Do whatever you want to do ;)

Comment: But everything in onload()?... sounds stupid

Comment: Welcome to the world of _Asynchronous Programming_

Comment: You will definitely come back and stay here forever once you understand it ;)