# FileReader readyState is stuck at 1 when loading a file in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, filereader

I am using FileReader in my web app to read a user-selected local file, and when I readAsText() the readyState should change to '2' once completed.  Here is the code I have:

```
        var fr = new FileReader(); // readyState is 0
        var filetoload = $("#foo")[0].files[0];
        fr.readAsText(filetoload); // readyState should be 2!!
        var xml = fr.result; 
        localStorage.setItem('foo', xml);
```

Now in Firefox, this all works fine and the xml gets written to the localStorage just fine.  If I do this Chrome in the console at a resting state (assuming there is a file specified in the #foo input) then it works as well.  BUT if I run this normally from the script tag in my .jsp file, readyState = 1 (!) after line 3 above.  AND, if I put a breakpoint on line 3, then try to readAsText() from the console, it sets readyState = 1 as well.

What does Chrome need to fully read the file during execution?  What am I doing wrong?  The fact that it works in Firefox and Chrome only during a resting state in the console leads me to believe there is something more that Chrome needs to allow this or something.  Any insight is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why a negative vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find an answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829537/html5-filereader-how-to-return-result).  Since reading the file happens asynchronously, I guess I needed to handle accordingly.  Below is what worked for me. (jsonCall() is just an internal function we have that basically calls $.ajax)  I hope this helps someone in the future.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#foo').on('click', function(e){
            readFile($("[name='filelocation']")[0].files[0], function(e) {
                // use e.target.result in callback...
                var data = { "xml" : e.target.result };
                jsonCall("myservlet", data, function() {
                    window.open(url, "_blank", "height=800,width=1200");
                })
            });
        });
    });

    function readFile(file, onLoadCallback)
        {
        var fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = onLoadCallback;
        fr.readAsText(file);
        }
```