# How to convert the selected file to blob format?

Tags: javascript, filereader

I have simple input-file field.

```
<input  type="file"
       id="openselect"
       name="files[]"
       (change)="fileSelect($event)">
```

It has related function that tries to convert selected file to BLOB format.

```
openselect.addEventListener("change", fileSelect, false);
function fileSelect(event) {
  const file = event.target['files'][0];
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.readAsText(file);
  console.log(fileReader.result)    // null
  console.log('iamge as blob: ', new Blob([fileReader.result]))        // meta info
}
```

As a result, console only displays file meta info, but doesnt display BLOB-string.

Please help me convert selected file to a BLOB-string.

Here is a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/oxcmjtwk/5/).

Comment: You forgot the `reader.addEventListener("load")` part : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at Mozilla's `FileReader` Documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/result):

> This example presents a function, read(), which reads a file from a file input. It works by creating a FileReader object and creating a listener for load events such that when then file is read, the result is obtained and passed to the callback function provided to read().

Solution: [Live Example](https://jsfiddle.net/xzyc2o4h/2/)

Another Question that might help you [HTML5 FileReader how to return result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829537/html5-filereader-how-to-return-result)